# Finding all elements in $I_{R/B}(A/B)$ and $(I_R(A))/B$ as following

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $A$ be a right ideal in $R$. Define $I_R(A) = \{r \in R | rA \subseteq A \}$. If $B$ be an ideal in $R$ and $B \subseteq A$, find all elements in $I_{R/B}(A/B)$ and $(I_R(A))/B$.

My attempt:

I found that
\begin{align*}
I_{R/B}(A/B) &= \{m \in R/B | m(A/B) \subseteq (A/B) \} \\
&= \{r \in R | (r+B)(a+B) \subseteq A/B, a \in A \} \\
&= \{r \in R | ra + B \subseteq A/B \subseteq A, a \in A \}
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
(I_R(A))/B &= \{x \in I_R(A) | x+B \subseteq A \} \\
&= \{r \in R | rA + B \subseteq A \} \\
&= \{r \in R | ra + B \subseteq A, a \in A \}
\end{align*}

Is that true? Please correct me if there are some mistakes. Thanks in advanced.